# okular snap package doesn't appear in applications and command 'okular' is not recognized

Tags: 17.10, snap, okular

I've installed okular from snap

```
snap list
Name              Version  Rev   Developer  Notes
core              16-2.30  3887  canonical  core
kde-frameworks-5  5.37.0   13    kde        -
okular            16.12.3  3     kde        -
```

when enter command `okular` in shell

```
okular
The program 'okular' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install okular
```

It also doesn't appear in the application list. **the only way to launch okular is from software center.**

[image]

Comment: there's no option 'add to dash/add to favourites' https://imgur.com/Op1F0bM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to launch Okular by the following command

```
snap run okular
```

If you want to add it to the applications list, you may create a `.desktop` file in `~/.local/share/applications/` (say `okular-snap.desktop`) with the following content and save it

```
[Desktop Entry]
Comment=Okular document reader
Terminal=false
Name=Okular
Exec=/snap/bin/okular
Type=Application
Icon=okular
NoDisplay=false
```

You may find an already existing `.desktop` launcher for the application in the `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/` directory. In that case just copy it to `~/.local/share/applications/`.

**If the correct icon is not appearing:**
You may set any image (preferably PNG or SVG) as the icon for the application. To do that change the `Icon=` line and point towards your preferred image. For example if you want use the `MyIcon.png` image located in your Desktop folder, change the line to

```
Icon=/home/YOUR_USER_NAME/Desktop/MyIcon.png
```

(Replace `YOUR_USER_NAME` by you actual username)
.

Comment: Thanks! this works. Is there any way to use okular icon? https://imgur.com/a/iFTMc

Comment: @TahsinRahman See the edit I made to the answer. Download an icon for Okular and make the change to the `.desktop` file.