# 17.10 Software installed in software center, but not accessible

Tags: software-center, 17.10

In Ubuntu 17.10 I installed applications from the software center. At first everything worked fine, but after a few days they kind of disappeared. They are neither found when searching in the dash, nor when the executable name directly in the terminal. However, the software center shows them still as installed and they can be launched from there. Any help to fix this strange behavior is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the softwares you have mentioned are installed via snap packages. You can check the list of installed snaps by running

```
snap list
```

You can individually launch an installed snap-software by running

```
snap run <package-name>
```

(replace `<package-name>` by a name found in the output of `snap list`).

To be able to find the software in "Activities" or "Show Applications" you'll have to create a custom `.desktop` file. See this Q&A for reference: [okular snap package doesn't appear in applications and command 'okular' is not recognized](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1000939/okular-snap-package-doesnt-appear-in-applications-and-command-okular-is-not-r)

Comment: Too difficult. Just installed Arduino (`arduino-mhall119`) snap on 17.10, rebooted, and it is shown in MATE *Applications->Programming->Arduino IDE*. Unity shows it in *Show Applications* too.